# Zabbix cross-compilation issue with HAVE_LONG_LONG condition test

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, powerpc, zabbix

I'm trying to cross-compile a Zabbix agent for an embedded Linux device (powerpc-8xx)
The configuration script fails on "checking for long long format..."
I've googled the issue and apparently Zabbix configure/configure.ac scripts are not cross-compile ready.
A guy proposed a nice patch [here](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5561?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) for configure.ac/configure.in file (added an extra `AC_MSG_RESULT(no)` row):

```
AC_TRY_RUN(
[
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
        uint64_t i;

        sscanf("200000000010020", "%qu", &i);

        if (i == 200000000010020) return 0;
        else return -1;
}
],
AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LONG_LONG_QU, 1 ,[Define to 1 if format '%qu' exists.])
AC_MSG_RESULT(yes),
+AC_MSG_RESULT(no),
AC_MSG_RESULT(no))
```

..but I cannot use autoconf/automake (because I'm using Debian Etch and it has an incompatible autoconf version, it's too old)

So I have to apply the same change, but with a different syntax to my ./configure file, specifically to these lines:

```
if ac_fn_c_try_run "$LINENO"; then :

$as_echo "#define HAVE_LONG_LONG_QU 1 " >>confdefs.h

{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
$as_echo "yes" >&6; }
else
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
$as_echo "no" >&6; }
fi
```

How do I port those changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run ./bootstrap.sh for the latest Zabbix 2.2 and for the patched version.

Here is the diff between the two ./configure versions:

```
$ diff -U 4 configure-original configure-patched
--- configure-original  2014-08-07 16:42:27.228887386 +0300
+++ configure-patched   2014-08-07 16:43:23.404887379 +0300
@@ -7326,12 +7326,10 @@

 { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for long long format" >&5
 $as_echo_n "checking for long long format... " >&6; }
 if test "$cross_compiling" = yes; then :
-  { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&5
-$as_echo "$as_me: error: in \`$ac_pwd':" >&2;}
-as_fn_error $? "cannot run test program while cross compiling
-See \`config.log' for more details" "$LINENO" 5; }
+  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: no" >&5
+$as_echo "no" >&6; }
 else
   cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
```

Comment: Those rows have different line numbers in my configure file, I've just applied the patch manually and it works!!! Thank you!
Do you want to post a ticket on Zabbix tracker?

Comment: The ticket on Zabbix tracker regarding this problem is the one you already mentioned - [ZBX-5561](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5561) and it is being worked on since yesterday. :-)

Comment: You could submit your patch for configuration files, like the guy who opened the ticket: https://support.zabbix.com/secure/attachment/20063/cross-comp.patch

Comment: I have attached the patch as you suggested. Thank you!